# XmlBPMNProcessDumper generated XML is not same as WorkBench designer generated XML

Tags: jbpm

I'm using XmlBPMNProcessDumper to generate BPMN XML. The result is defferent when I compare it to what generated by workbench designer. Is there any other Class to generate it properly?

Answer (score 0):

They are not meant to be identical, though they should be (mostly) semantically equivalent (from a runtime perspective at least).  What are you trying to achieve?  Note that the models generated by designer / Eclipse are using the Eclipse BPMN2 EMF model to generate the XML.

Comment: I'm working on a web-based process designer. I want to generate a BPMN2 XML resource and deploy it on a standalone jBPM server installed on a separate server which installed using jbpm-installer. I just wanted to know what's best approach? Because when I open generated process in jBPM workbench, some in/out mapping fields are different than when using workbench to create the process.